# Why is displacement negative during free fall?

Tags: coordinate-systems, conventions, free-fall, displacement

I am confused by this question. Displacement is shortest path travelled by an object, but I had seen in my book that during free fall displacement is negative.

Comment: Negative sign stands for opposite direction. It's a vector after all!

Answer (score 1):

Displacement is the vector version of distance, so it has a magnitude (the distance) and a *direction*. If the motion is only in one dimension, as in free fall, then the direction manifests only as positive and negative, or up and down but you are free to define whether up is positive or negative (and similarly for down) as long as you are consistent within the problem/analysis.

It looks like your book takes up as being positive, so that as something falls downwards in free fall, its displacement increases in the negative direction, ie gets more and more negative.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I throw a ball from my chest-height straight up into the air: it travels upwards for a time $\tau$ before it reaches its maximum, then it falls down for a time $\tau$ too. We know that it achieves the height $h = \frac 1 2 ~g~\tau^2$ above my chest-height in this time where $g \approx \text{9.81 m/s}^2$, so if we take my chest-height as the value $y=0$, and upwards as positive, then the **position** or **displacement** $y$ of the ball can be written as a function of time like $$y(t) = \frac 1 2 ~g~ \tau^2 - \frac 1 2 ~ g ~ (t - \tau)^2$$**Exercise**: plug in $t = 0$, $t = \tau$, $t = 2\tau$ to confirm that the ball does what you expect it to do. Derive that the ball's speed of launch as it left my hands must have been $v_0 = g \tau$.

Notice that this is not the **distance** the ball travels, because it reaches a maximum and then comes back down to zero. Once the ball comes back down to chest-height, it has not traveled a distance zero, but rather the distance $g \tau^2$. In fact the distance traveled since time $t=0$ is the complicated function:$$d(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}y(t)&\text{if } t < \tau;\\ g~ \tau^2 - y(t)&\text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$Notice that the distance traveled is only negative for $t < 0$, which is exactly when we say the ball started moving (in other words, the equation's not valid for $t < 0$ and nothing about this would make sense). The function is, we say, *monotonically increasing*: if $t_1 > t_0$ then $d(t_1) \ge d(t_0)$. That property is key to what we mean by "distance" rather than "displacement": the distance that something has traveled **never decreases** with time, but only increases or possibly stays the same (if it's at a stand-still).

Once you know the difference between these two words: position/displacement versus distance, we can now talk about how a *displacement* may go negative. That is actually very simple: **I don't catch the ball.** Now it keeps traveling to a new position $y=-c$, where $c$ is my chest height: in other words, it hits the floor.

You see, I was free to choose $y=0$ as whatever height I wanted, to start with. But, if something goes beneath that height, I have to represent its position with a negative number. But *that's OK* because negative numbers work just like normal numbers.

Or I could choose $y=0$ to be the floor height: then my earlier function becomes the slightly-more-complicated $$y(t) = c + \frac 1 2 ~g~ \tau^2 - \frac 1 2 ~ g ~ (t - \tau)^2$$Except maybe that doesn't solve the problem. Maybe what I didn't tell you is that this "ball" is a *cannonball* and it falls through the floor: you need negative coordinates again!

So negative coordinates are usually really useful, they're the only way to be truly universal, and sometimes they're even important.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between **displacement** and **position**. **Position** is a vector measured relative to a defined origin and is often designated by the vector symbol $\vec{r}$. In a Cartesian coordinate system, $$
\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k},$$
where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the individual coordinate values, positive or negative, relative to the origin.

**Displacement** is a vector which describes a *change* in position, usually shown with a delta sign, $\Delta$:
$$\Delta \vec{r} = \vec{r}_{new}-\vec{r}_{old}.$$
The position of a particle could be described as the displacement from the origin.

Consider a particle which starts at position $\vec{r}_1 = (15\ m)\hat{i}$ and after some time arrives (by unknown means) at position $\vec{r}_2 = (-3\ m)\hat{j}$. The displacement over this time interval would be $\Delta\vec{r}= (-18\ m)\hat{j}$. The displacement magnitude is 18 m and the direction of displacement is $-\hat{j}$. You don't actually know how far the particle travelled (it could have been anywhere because I didn't tell you anything about its motion or how much time elapsed) or whether the particle travelled up, down, left, right, etc, because I didn't give you any description of the coordinate system as it relates to physical surroundings.  Now if I tell you that $+\hat{j}$ is opposite the gravitational field, i.e., $+\hat{j}$ is ``up'', then you know the particle eventually moved down.  If I tell you the velocity was constant, you know it moved directly down.  If I tell you the particle started from rest, and gravity was the only force, you know it moved directly down and you can relate the time to the gravitational field.

Because both displacement and position are vectors related to a coordinate system, one needs to carefully and specifically choose what direction is the positive direction for each coordinate.  If you don't make this choice, you will run into all kinds of problems when trying to describe how a particle moves.

Answer (score 0):

The sign is simply a convention: a convention is being used which identifies motion away from the large, gravitational body (against gravity) as having a positive sign. Thus motion in the direction of gravity is negative.

This convention is useful because when we perform work on an object by raising it against  against gravity, we increase its gravitational potential energy. If we use a positive sign for the motion, then the work applied, positive energy potential increase and displacement are all positive.

Also, the convention follows simply from the measure of distance between two bodies. If we are considering two bodies in space, like the Earth and Moon, we have little reason to think of the distance between them as a negative number.  If they move such that they are closer together, then that is a negative delta in the positive distance measure which separates them.

We can identify bodies using points in a coordinate system, which are vectors. The path between them is then the difference between their two position vectors. The difference can be calculated in either direction; either way, the distance is positive because it is the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) of that displacement vector.